# vba code to loop data from multiple workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I am in need of a little help getting this code going. I have a master workbook that has 20+ sheets in it. Each employee has their own sheet title Employee-(Worker's name). I created a temp file (All workbooks are saved here) and each workbook is a duplicate of the sheets titled Employee-(worker's name) and the workbook's file name is (worker's name).xlsm

Each worker can then update their workbooks and those updates are sent to the (worker's name).xlsm workbook which in turn will be looped to the Master workbook at the end of the day to update those sheets that are name exactly the same in each workerbook.

Here's a code that someone had given me but I'm not really sure where to put it or how to go about doing my goal above.

```
myFolder$ = 
“C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Workbooks”currFile$ = Dir(myFolder)While Not currFile = 
vbNullStringWorkbooks.Open(myFolder & 
“\” & currFile)‘// Copy data code hereWorkbooks(currFile).Close 
FalsecurrFile = 
Dir()Wend
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something to get you going (I am not sure I can help you with all your mission):

```
Sub Test1()
myFolder$ = "C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Workbooks" & "\"
currFile$ = Dir(myFolder)

' EDIT -While Not currFile = vbNullStringWorkbooks
While Not currFile = vbNullString
    ' !!! I DO NO KNOW WHAT THIS IS :
    ' ---------------------------------
    'Open(myFolder & "\" & currFile)
    ' ‘// Copy data code hereWorkbooks(currFile).Close
    'False
    ' ---------------------------------
    currFile = Dir()
Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: I added that, but it's not really doing anything. I don't know if maybe I'm missing something. In the comments you have stuff written, but I'm not sure if I'm suppose to add stuff there.

Comment: The code above loops over the existing files of the C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Workbooks   folder.     This is something to help to get started. If you want to work of the file, then you need to add relevant code inside the loop.

Comment: That make sense. I don't have any coding though. I'm not really  good at coding. This code is something I got over the internet. So essentially I would add the code to extract the data from the workbooks and paste it onto my master workbook?

Comment: It is a bit a hard for me to understand the entire process, but it seems that that is the right direction (BTW- I did an edit and correct the loop condition).